# How to get polygon points from image?

Tags: php, image, 2d, ocr, shapes

I need to get programmatically polygon points coordinates from image.

Here is an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUpiI.jpg

Is there any libraries or any solutions for this? Desirable written in php.

Comment: Fortunately or unfortunately, depending on your perspective, requests for library/book/tutorial recommendations are off-topic here, since they have historically attracted spam. You _might_ have more luck on our sister site _Software Recs_, but please read their posting guidelines first (at the very least, this is not nearly detailed enough).